# ASP Core 3 react template, HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated() returns False after login

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

After working on my project for a while, I released the `HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated()` returns False after login and I need to know where I should look for the mistake I made that cause this problem.
This is the Login, OnPost method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.StudentNumber == Input.StudentNumber.ToString());
        if (!(user is null) && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password))
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, Input.RememberMe);
        var isUserAuthenticated = HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated();
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
  }
```

The ConfigureServices method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddAutoMapper();

     services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

     services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(option=>option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric=false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

     services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

     services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

     services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
     services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
     {
           configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
     });
}
```

The Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
   }
   else
   {
       app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
       // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
       app.UseHsts();
   }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you have the password, you can use `PasswordSignInAsync` instead. It returns a `SignInResult` that you can check for success or to see what the error was. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync

Comment: @crgolden I did try that one too but though the result was successful, the `IsAuthenticated` property was False.

Comment: What does `IsSignedIn` return? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.issignedin

Comment: Since you're using `UserManager` and `SignInManager`, why are you trying to also access `HttpContext` directly? Doing that makes things much more difficult to unit test later, since you can't really mock `HttpContext`...

Comment: @crgolden The `IsSignedIn` also returns False.
I probably not gonna use unit test on the project and I don't care about `HttpContext`. I just need to access authenticated user in an API but the API returns 401 error.

Comment: Does the API endpoint have the `[Authorize]` attribute on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SignInManager.SignInAsync()` only creates the cookie for the given user. This method would not set `HttpContext.User`.

But in the next request which has the cookie you can access `HttpContext.User` after `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated()` should be true.

`AuthenticationMiddleware` always try to authenticate user with the default scheme and since you have `AddIdentityServer` after `AddDefaultIdentity`, identity server is becoming your default scheme, but when you call `SignInManager.SignInAsync` the `Identity` scheme is triggered.

To sum up, with this configuration your `AuthenticationMiddleware` always tries to authenticate request for `IdentityServer` and if you want other scheme for you apis you should use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]`.

P.S. `Identity.Application` is authenticatio scheme for ASP.NET Identity

Comment: In next requests the `HttpContext.User.IsAuthenticated()` are False and I get 401 error when I want to access to an authorize API.
It's also a little bit weird because react navbar component will update to user authenticated view and show email of the user.

Comment: I get this error "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type". Lookalikes the error means the attribute parameters should be constant and be known at compile time.

Comment: Yeah. Worked. Would you turn it into an answer?

Comment: Based on your update reversed the order of `services.AddDefaultIdentity` and` services.AddAuthentication` and turned the attribute back to just `[Authorize]` and that worked too. I just wanted to know if there is any issue with this approach or it's fine and it's not going to cause any problems.

Comment: That would case another problems, since now `IdentityServer` rely on default authentication scheme